# How to find all references to a method programmatically?

Tags: java, migration

So, this isn't how to find method references using Eclipse IDE.

I need to find them via code (Java).

**Background:**
We have hundreds of projects, all based off a common project.  Over the years, the common project has some really bad code that has been replaced.  The bad code has been marked as Deprecated.

Now, I want to remove all the deprecated code.  But, I want to create some code to migrate all the other projects we have.

**Approach:**
Now, for some things, I could search the project code for some keywords (i.e method name) and replace with something else.  However, there are some method names that would collide and doing a simple search/replace would not work.

My thought is, if I have a deprecated method:
com.foo.bar.SomeClass.someMethod(String)

Then some way to find every place that someMethod(String) is used, I could then replace that one with newMethod(String)

I have looked some at:

- [org.reflections.Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)
- [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/)

Basically, I want to create a migration program to make migrating to the new common code simple. I plan to use this same migration code to help migrate the projects from JDK8 to OpenJDK11.

Thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: When you compile the various projects, the compiler output should show you all uses of deprecated methods.  If it isn’t doing that, enable the compiler warning for deprecation.  If building on the command line, you would do it with `-Xlint:deprecation`.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use ASM with a ClassVisitor / MethodVisitor to find all references to this method.

You just have to override `visitMethod` in the `ClassVisitor` to return your own `MethodVisitor`, and in the `MethodVisitor` override `visitMethodInsn`.

In the visitMethodInsn you check if the target is one of the deprecated methods, and log where it is used. Here an example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;

import static org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.*;

public class MethodScanner extends ClassVisitor {

    private final String fileName;

    private MethodScanner(String fileName) {
        super(ASM7);
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        scanJar(new File("path/to/some.jar"));

    }

    public static void scanJar(File jarFile) throws IOException {
        var jf = new JarFile(jarFile);

        jf.stream().filter(je -> getFileExtension(je.getName()).equals(".class"))
        .forEach(je -> processEntry(jf, je));
    }

    private static String getFileExtension(String name) {
        int idx = name.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (idx == -1)
            return "";
        return name.substring(idx);
    }

    private static void processEntry(JarFile jf, JarEntry je) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = jf.getInputStream(je).readAllBytes();
            MethodScanner ms = new MethodScanner(jf.getName() + "!" + je.getName());
            ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(bytes);
            cr.accept(ms, 0);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String descriptor, String signature,
            String[] exceptions) {
        return new MethodScannerVisitor(super.visitMethod(access, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions), fileName, name + descriptor);
    }

    private static class MethodScannerVisitor extends MethodVisitor {

        private final String fileName;
        private final String methodName;

        private MethodScannerVisitor(MethodVisitor parent, String fileName, String methodName) {
            super(ASM7, parent);
            this.fileName = fileName;
            this.methodName = methodName;
        }

        @Override
        public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String descriptor, boolean isInterface) {
            super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, descriptor, isInterface);
            if (owner.equals("java/lang/Math") && name.equals("random") && descriptor.equals("()D")) {
                System.out.println("reference to Math.random() from " + fileName + " in " + methodName);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I will add an example once eclipse has started. My computer is rater slow, so it may take a while.

Comment: Yes, it does.  I realized doing code to try to migrate is going to be more of a pain than what it is worth.  Plus, many of the changes can't really be done with a search/replace.  I am just going to have to use Eclipse to find the depreciated code and update as-needed.

Answer (score 0):

Doing some searching, I have some base code, but still not going 100%

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;


public class ProjectMigration {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    ProjectMigration migration = new ProjectMigration();
    try {
      migration.migrate();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private List<DeprecatedClass> getDeprecatedMethods () {
    List<DeprecatedClass> deprecatedClasses = new ArrayList<>();
    deprecatedClasses.add(
        new DeprecatedClass("com.e2open.selenium.api_common.abstractHelpers.SystemInformation",
            "isInternetExplorer8", "boolean", ""));
    deprecatedClasses.add(
        new DeprecatedClass("com.e2open.selenium.api_common.AbstractPage", "radioButtonSelect",
            "boolean", "java.lang.String", "java.lang.String"));

    return deprecatedClasses;
  }

  public void migrate ()
      throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    List<DeprecatedClass> deprecatedClasses = getDeprecatedMethods();

    for (DeprecatedClass clazz : deprecatedClasses) {
      System.out.println("CLASS: " + clazz.getClazz());
      Class c = Class.forName(clazz.getClazz());
      analyze(c.newInstance(), clazz);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  private void analyze (Object object, DeprecatedClass deprecatedClass) {

    ClassVisitor cv = new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5) {
      @Override
      public MethodVisitor visitMethod (
          int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {

        if (isDeprecatedMethod(deprecatedClass, name, desc)) {
          logMethod(name, desc);
          return new MethodVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5) {
            @Override
            public void visitMethodInsn (
                int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc, boolean arg4) {
              if (owner.contains("e2open")) {
                processMethod(owner, name, desc);
              }
              super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc, arg4);
            }
          };
        }
        return null;
      }
    };
    try {
      ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(object.getClass().getCanonicalName());
      classReader.accept(cv, 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Something went wrong !! " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  protected void processMethod (String owner, String name, String desc) {
    System.out.println(
        "classUsed[" + owner.replace("/", ".") + "]; methodUsed[" + name + "]; methodParameters["
            + desc + "]");
  }

  protected void logMethod (String name, String desc) {
    String returnType = getReturnType(desc);
    String paramters = getParamters(desc);
    System.out.println(String.format("METHOD: %s %s(%s)", returnType, name, paramters));
  }



  private String getParamters (String desc) {
    String parms = desc.split("\\)")[0];
    if (parms.equals("(")) {
      return "";
    }
    parms = parms.substring(2, parms.length());
    String[] parmameters = parms.split(";");
    StringBuilder paramterString = new StringBuilder();
    for (String p : parmameters) {
      paramterString.append(p.replaceAll("/", ".")).append(", ");
    }
    return paramterString.toString().substring(0, paramterString.length() - 2);
  }

  private String getReturnType (String desc) {
    String returnType = desc.split("\\)")[1];
    if (returnType.equals("V")) {
      return "void";
    }
    if (returnType.length() == 1) {
      return returnType;
    }
    return returnType.substring(1, returnType.length() - 1).replace("/", ".");
  }

  private boolean isDeprecatedMethod (
      DeprecatedClass deprecatedClass, String method, String parmeters) {
    if ((method.equals(deprecatedClass.getMethod()))
        && (parmeters.equals(deprecatedClass.getParameters()))) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }


  private class DeprecatedClass {
    private String clazz;
    private String method;
    private List<String> parameters;
    private String returnType;

    public DeprecatedClass() {}

    /**
     * No paramters and no return type
     *
     * @param clazzName The class to check. Example: com.e2open.selenium.api_common.AbstractPage
     * @param methodName The method name to find references for. Example: clearAllInputFields
     */
    public DeprecatedClass(String clazzName, String methodName) {
      this.clazz = clazzName;
      this.method = methodName;
    }

    /**
     * Use if there is a return type and/or parameters
     *
     * @param clazzName The class to check. Example: com.e2open.selenium.api_common.AbstractPage
     * @param methodName he method name to find references for. Example: findFieldByAttribute
     * @param returnType The returned type. Example: org.openqa.selenium.By
     * @param parameterValues List of paramters. Example: "java.lang.String", "java.lang.String",
     *        "java.lang.String"
     */
    public DeprecatedClass(String clazzName, String methodName, String returnType,
        String... parameterValues) {
      this.clazz = clazzName;
      this.method = methodName;
      setReturnType(returnType);
      if (parameterValues != null) {
        for (String parm : parameterValues) {
          if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(parm)) {
            addParameter(parm);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * @return the clazz
     */
    public String getClazz () {
      return clazz;
    }

    /**
     * @param clazz the clazz to set
     */
    public void setClazz (String clazz) {
      this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    /**
     * @return the method
     */
    public String getMethod () {
      return method;
    }

    /**
     * @param method the method to set
     */
    public void setMethod (String method) {
      this.method = method;
    }


    /**
     * @param returnType the returnType to set
     */
    public void setReturnType (String returnType) {
      if (returnType != null) {
        if ("boolean".equals(returnType)) {
          this.returnType = "Z";
        } else {
          this.returnType = "L" + returnType.replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ";";
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * @return the parameters
     */
    public String getParameters () {
      StringBuilder parms = new StringBuilder();
      if (this.parameters == null) {
        parms.append("()");
      } else {
        parms.append("(").append(String.join("", this.parameters)).append(")");
      }

      if (this.returnType == null) {
        parms.append("V");
      } else {
        parms.append(this.returnType);
      }
      return parms.toString();
    }

    /**
     * @param parameters the parameters to set
     */
    public void addParameter (String parameter) {
      if (this.parameters == null) {
        this.parameters = new ArrayList<>();
      }

      this.parameters.add("L" + parameter.replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ";");
    }


  }

}
```

The results I get is:

```
CLASS: com.e2open.selenium.api_common.abstractHelpers.SystemInformation
METHOD: Z isInternetExplorer8()
classUsed[com.e2open.selenium.api_common.abstractHelpers.SystemInformation]; methodUsed[getSystemData]; methodParameters[()Lcom/e2open/selenium/api_common/abstractHelpers/SystemInformation$SystemData;]
classUsed[com.e2open.selenium.api_common.browser.BrowserType]; methodUsed[equals]; methodParameters[(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z]

CLASS: com.e2open.selenium.api_common.AbstractPage
METHOD: Z radioButtonSelect(java.lang.String, Ljava.lang.String)
classUsed[com.e2open.selenium.api_common.JLog]; methodUsed[write]; methodParameters[(Ljava/lang/String;)V]
classUsed[com.e2open.selenium.api_common.AbstractPage]; methodUsed[radioButtonGet]; methodParameters[(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebElement;]
```

However, the results are not correct.

If I take one of the methods:
com.e2open.selenium.api_common.abstractHelpers.SystemInformation.isInternetExplorer8()

And use Eclipse to find References, I get
[isInternetExplorer8 Eclipse References Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeTdh.png)

And for the other method doing a search on:  
com.e2open.selenium.api_common.AbstractPage.radioButtonSelect(String, String)  
[radioButtonSelect Eclipse Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQcvM.png)

I am unsure what to change or where to go from here.

Comment: You print out methods that are used by the deprecated methods, not the other way around (methods that use the deprecated methods).